Is this schematic correct for "light activated switch using pic18f4550"? Also, is the program correct?

    #include <xc.h>
    #define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000  // Define crystal frequency
    
    void init_ADC(void)
    {
        // Set RA0 as input
        TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;
    
        // Configure ADC
        ADCON1 = 0x0E;  // Set AN0 as analog input
        ADCON2 = 0xA9;  // Right justified, 20TAD, Fosc/8
        ADCON0 = 0x01;  // Turn on ADC, select channel 0 (AN0)
    }
    
    unsigned int read_ADC(void)
    {
        ADCON0bits.GO = 1;  // Start conversion
        while(ADCON0bits.GO);  // Wait for conversion to finish
        return ((ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL);  // Return 10-bit result
    }
    
    void main(void)
    {
        unsigned int adc_value;
        unsigned int threshold = 500;  // Set a threshold value for LDR (you can calibrate this)
    
        // Setup
        TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;  // RD0 as output (connected to relay)
        LATDbits.LATD0 = 0;    // Initially keep relay off
    
        init_ADC();  // Initialize ADC
    
        while(1)
        {
            adc_value = read_ADC();  // Read LDR value
    
            // Compare ADC value with threshold
            if(adc_value < threshold)  // Torch is near the LDR (light is stronger)
            {
                LATDbits.LATD0 = 1;  // Turn off the relay (lamp off)
            }
            else  // Torch is far from the LDR (darkness increases resistance)
            {
                LATDbits.LATD0 = 0;  // Turn on the relay (lamp on)
            }
    
            __delay_ms(500);  // Small delay for debounce
        }
    }


Please [edit] your question, select the block of code and press the { } preformatted text button which will format it as code and preserve indentation. Welcome to the forum.

Regarding the schematic: 1. Where are U1's power connections? 2. Where does LDR1(1) come from?

Is the program correct? ... that cannot be answered ... you did not say what you expect the program to do

It might work in the simulator, but no, the schematics have many errors. I did not read the code. But you have drawn it in the simulator, if they don't work, you can see why it does not work. Sounds like you did something for homework, and instead of trying anything, you asked here.


is this schematic is correct for "light activated switch using
pic18f4550"

I'd say there was a pretty fundamental error in your crystal oscillator circuit: -

Also, where are the GND connections to your MCU? What power supply capacitor decoupling regime have you adopted?
Fix the hardware errors before going on to explain what your code is intended to do (in a new post) then asking about the code.
